# how to write on next line using javascript innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

This is my code:

```
document.getElementById("customerInfoLabel").innerHTML = "Trip Type: " + gettriptype + "\n Leaving From: " + getdeparture;
```

I want to something like this:

```
Trip Type: One Way
Leaving From: Melbourne
```

What it is currently giving me is this:

```
Trip Type: One Way Leaving From: Melbourne
```

Comment: Have you tried using a <br> tag instead of the \n?

Answer (score 1):

Try `<br/>` instead

```
document.getElementById("customerInfoLabel").innerHTML = "Trip Type: " + gettriptype + "<br/> Leaving From: " + getdeparture;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look it up in the internet.

Two alternatives:

- use the `<br>` tag instead of \n
- use a style:

  ```
  #customerInfoLabel {
      whitespace: pre;
  }
  ```

Learn about the whitespace behaviour on html. developer.mozilla.org is a good source.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, use br instead of /n
Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7GGM/)

```
document.getElementById("customerInfoLabel").innerHTML = "Trip Type: " + gettriptype + "<br>Leaving From: " + getdeparture;
```